# Hive create table : parse error missing ">" while parsing json file

Tags: json, hive

I am getting the following exception while creating the hive table. Can anybody point me the error? 
Sample input:{"user":{"userlocation":"Bolton, UK","id":14141159,"name":"Chris Beckett","screenname":"ChrisBeckett","geoenabled":true},"tweetmessage":"vCOps people - Does Advanced Edition == 5 VMs? I know Std has UI and analytics VM, but what does rest use? Hyperic etc? #vmware #vcops","createddate":"2013-06-20T12:08:46","geolocation":null}

```
enter code here

   CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS twitter(
   users map<string,string,string,string,string>,
   message string,
    createddate string,
    geolocation string
  )
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.JsonSerde'
  LOCATION ' /user/root/hadoop_tests/sample_twitter_data.txt';
```

> 

```
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

FAILED: ParseException line 2:23 missing > at ',' near 'string' in column type
line 2:30 cannot recognize input near ',' 'string' ',' in column type

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use Struct instead of Map.Below:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS twitter(
   users  struct<userlocation:string,id:string,name:string,screenname:string,geoenabled:string>,
   message string,
   createddate string,
   geolocation string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.JsonSerde'
LOCATION '/user/root/hadoop_tests/';
```

Comment: Yes, realized I should be using struct. I made that change but the data is getting loaded as Null for some reason. Only the createddate field is getting picked. All the other columns data is null. Any idea